# IIS Permanent Redirects

Tags: iis, redirect, permanent

I have seen a few things written about this and remember one where there was an XML file. So, there is an old URL and a new URL. If the user hits the old URL he is redirected to the new one.

The redirects can be from files that don't exist on the server eg new-jobs.php from Apache server has been moved to an IIS Server and the file is now called new-jobs.aspx.

Does anyone know of such a system or have a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [URLRewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).